# Salesforce AWS EventRelay refuses to connect to AWS DEV after sandbox refresh

Tags: sandbox, platform-event, aws

In November I set up a SF Event Relay for AWS Eventbridge in our DEV SF sandbox which pointed to our DEV AWS account using the Named Credential, Event Relay, Event Channel, Published Events process, and everything worked great.

Following tests, I then did the same in our SF Production which pointed to our Production AWS Account. Everything was great there, too.

Weeks later, I refreshed our Dev SF Sandbox. We re-added a named credential for our AWS Dev Account, set up an event relay, SF notes a connection was made...but to our Production AWS Account(?!) not our DEV AWS Account. No matter how many times we deleted and re-activated, it seems the Event Relay *always* points to our PROD AWS.

Has anyone else experienced this? Unfortunately we are a non-profit on Enterprise, and SF refuses to support this inquiry without premier support.

/J

Comment: When did you refresh the sandbox last time? Also what is your sandbox org version?